# How to Use Array From A Function Without Have Relation with That Function in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, arrays, encryption, cryptography

i know maybe this is a dumbest question and the question title ever but it's really seriously i have been stuck here for a long time.

Here is it i want to create a cryptography app which to encrypt a text and decrypt it again. I have doing all well and encryption section are done.

There are just two button on my app, which is encrypt and decrypt. When encrypt button pressed, it'l run a function that gonna produce an array named resultXOR. And when decrypt button pressed, i need the resultXOR array to doing the decryption progress. But here i don't know how to take it from encrypt function.

Here i attach my code also, on function toASCII i got that problem. There are the value on resultXOR and i need it for the decrypt section.

Please master help me. 
Thanks.

NB. this the code so far i can create :

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_aesandroid);
    final Button enkripButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.enkrip_button);
    final Button dekripButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dekrip_button);
    final EditText inputKunci = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_kunci);
    final EditText inputKata = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_kata);
    final EditText teksEnkrip = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.teks_enkrip);
    final EditText teksDekrip = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.teks_dekrip);
    final TextView txtResultXOR = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtResultXOR);

    // set Instance

     // String [] kunciArrNumb=null;
    // handling for enkripButton
    enkripButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String ambilKunci = inputKunci.getText().toString();
            String ambilKata = inputKata.getText().toString();
            int jumKun = ambilKunci.length();
            int jumKat = ambilKata.length();
            String enKata = "";

            //int jumKun=jumKat;
            if(jumKun<jumKat){
                inputKunci.setError("Karakter kata kunci tidak boleh kurang dari pesan ");
            }else {
                jumKun=jumKat;
                String[] kunciArrNumb = toNumberKunci(ambilKunci, jumKun);
                //kunciArrNumb
                String[] kataArrNumb = toNumberKata(ambilKata, jumKat);
                //kataArrNumb
                ci(kunciArrNumb, kataArrNumb, jumKat, ambilKunci);
            }
        }
    });

    dekripButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String ambilKataHasil = teksEnkrip.getText().toString();
            String ambilKunci = inputKunci.getText().toString();
            int jumKun = ambilKunci.length();
            int jumKat = ambilKataHasil.length();

            ASCIIXOR(ambilKunci, ambilKataHasil, jumKat);
        }
    });

}

public void ci(String[] kunciArrNumb, String[] kataArrNumb,int jumKat, String ambilKunci){
    int[] hasilCi= new int[jumKat];
    String[] konversiCi= new String[jumKat];

    for(int i=0;i<jumKat;i++){
        hasilCi[i]=(Integer.parseInt(kunciArrNumb[i])+Integer.parseInt(kataArrNumb[i])) % 26;
        Log.d("mod", String.valueOf(hasilCi[i]));
    }

    for(int i=0;i<jumKat;i++){
        if(hasilCi[i] == 0){
            konversiCi[i]="a";
        }
        else if(hasilCi[i] == 1){
            konversiCi[i]="b";
        }
        else if(hasilCi[i] == 2 ){
            konversiCi[i]="c";
        }
        else if(hasilCi[i] == 3){
            konversiCi[i]="d";
        }
        else if(hasilCi[i] == 4){
            konversiCi[i]="e";
        }
        else if(hasilCi[i] == 5 ){
            konversiCi[i]="f";
        }
        else if(hasilCi[i] == 6){
            konversiCi[i]="g";
        }
        else if(hasilCi[i] == 7 ){
            konversiCi[i]="h";
        }
        else if(hasilCi[i] == 8){
            konversiCi[i]="i";
        }
        else if(hasilCi[i] == 9 ){
            konversiCi[i]="j";
        }
        else if(hasilCi[i] ==10 ){
            konversiCi[i]="k";
        }
        else if(hasilCi[i] == 11){
            konversiCi[i]="l";
        }
        else if(hasilCi[i] ==12 ){
            konversiCi[i]="m";
        }
        else if(hasilCi[i] == 13){
            konversiCi[i]="n";
        }
        else if(hasilCi[i] ==14 ){
            konversiCi[i]="o";
        }
        else if(hasilCi[i] ==15 ){
            konversiCi[i]="p";
        }
        else if(hasilCi[i] ==16 ){
            konversiCi[i]="q";
        }
        else if(hasilCi[i] == 17){
            konversiCi[i]="r";
        }
        else if(hasilCi[i] ==18 ){
            konversiCi[i]="s";
        }
        else if(hasilCi[i] == 19 ){
            konversiCi[i]="t";
        }
        else if(hasilCi[i] == 20 ){
            konversiCi[i]="u";
        }
        else if(hasilCi[i] == 21){
            konversiCi[i]="v";
        }
        else if(hasilCi[i] == 22){
            konversiCi[i]="w";
        }
        else if(hasilCi[i] == 23){
            konversiCi[i]="x";
        }
        else if(hasilCi[i] ==24 ){
            konversiCi[i]="y";
        }
        else if(hasilCi[i] ==25 ){
            konversiCi[i]="z";
        }
    }String leno = new String();
    for(int i=0;i<jumKat;i++){
        leno = leno +konversiCi[i];
    }
    Log.d("cuk", leno);

    //teksEnkrip.setText(leno);
    toASCII(leno, jumKat, ambilKunci);
}

public String[] toNumberKata(String ambilKata, int jumKat) {
    String[] kunciArr = ambilKata.split("(?<=\\G.{1})");
    //int jumKat = ambilKata.length();
    int alpha = 26;
    String[] kataArrNumb = new String[jumKat];

    for (int i = 0; i < jumKat; i++) {
        if (kunciArr[i].equals("A") || kunciArr[i].equals("a")) {
            kataArrNumb[i] = "0";
        } else if (kunciArr[i].equals("B") || kunciArr[i].equals("b")) {
            kataArrNumb[i] = "1";
        } else if (kunciArr[i].equals("C") || kunciArr[i].equals("c")) {
            kataArrNumb[i] = "2";
        } else if (kunciArr[i].equals("D") || kunciArr[i].equals("d")) {
            kataArrNumb[i] = "3";
        } else if (kunciArr[i].equals("E") || kunciArr[i].equals("e")) {
            kataArrNumb[i] = "4";
        } else if (kunciArr[i].equals("F") || kunciArr[i].equals("f")) {
            kataArrNumb[i] = "5";
        } else if (kunciArr[i].equals("G") || kunciArr[i].equals("g")) {
            kataArrNumb[i] = "6";
        } else if (kunciArr[i].equals("H") || kunciArr[i].equals("h")) {
            kataArrNumb[i] = "7";
        } else if (kunciArr[i].equals("I") || kunciArr[i].equals("i")) {
            kataArrNumb[i] = "8";
        } else if (kunciArr[i].equals("J") || kunciArr[i].equals("j")) {
            kataArrNumb[i] = "9";
        } else if (kunciArr[i].equals("K") || kunciArr[i].equals("k")) {
            kataArrNumb[i] = "10";
        } else if (kunciArr[i].equals("L") || kunciArr[i].equals("l")) {
            kataArrNumb[i] = "11";
        } else if (kunciArr[i].equals("M") || kunciArr[i].equals("m")) {
            kataArrNumb[i] = "12";
        } else if (kunciArr[i].equals("N") || kunciArr[i].equals("n")) {
            kataArrNumb[i] = "13";
        } else if (kunciArr[i].equals("O") || kunciArr[i].equals("o")) {
            kataArrNumb[i] = "14";
        } else if (kunciArr[i].equals("P") || kunciArr[i].equals("p")) {
            kataArrNumb[i] = "15";
        } else if (kunciArr[i].equals("Q") || kunciArr[i].equals("q")) {
            kataArrNumb[i] = "16";
        } else if (kunciArr[i].equals("R") || kunciArr[i].equals("r")) {
            kataArrNumb[i] = "17";
        } else if (kunciArr[i].equals("S") || kunciArr[i].equals("s")) {
            kataArrNumb[i] = "18";
        } else if (kunciArr[i].equals("T") || kunciArr[i].equals("t")) {
            kataArrNumb[i] = "19";
        } else if (kunciArr[i].equals("U") || kunciArr[i].equals("u")) {
            kataArrNumb[i] = "20";
        } else if (kunciArr[i].equals("V") || kunciArr[i].equals("v")) {
            kataArrNumb[i] = "21";
        } else if (kunciArr[i].equals("W") || kunciArr[i].equals("w")) {
            kataArrNumb[i] = "22";
        } else if (kunciArr[i].equals("X") || kunciArr[i].equals("x")) {
            kataArrNumb[i] = "23";
        } else if (kunciArr[i].equals("Y") || kunciArr[i].equals("y")) {
            kataArrNumb[i] = "24";
        } else if (kunciArr[i].equals("Z") || kunciArr[i].equals("z")) {
            kataArrNumb[i] = "25";
        } else {
            kataArrNumb[i].valueOf(alpha + Integer.parseInt(kunciArr[i]));
        }

    }return kataArrNumb;
}

public String[] toNumberKunci(String ambilKunci, int jumKun){
        String[] kunciArr = ambilKunci.split("(?<=\\G.{1})");
        //int jumKun = ambilKunci.length();
        int alpha=26;
        String[] kunciArrNumb= new String[jumKun];

        for(int i=0;i<jumKun;i++){
            if(kunciArr[i].equals("A") || kunciArr[i].equals("a")){
                kunciArrNumb[i]="0";
            }
            else if(kunciArr[i].equals("B") || kunciArr[i].equals("b")){
                kunciArrNumb[i]="1";
            }
            else if(kunciArr[i].equals("C") || kunciArr[i].equals("c")){
                kunciArrNumb[i]="2";
            }
            else if(kunciArr[i].equals("D") || kunciArr[i].equals("d")){
                kunciArrNumb[i]="3";
            }
            else if(kunciArr[i].equals("E") || kunciArr[i].equals("e")){
                kunciArrNumb[i]="4";
            }
            else if(kunciArr[i].equals("F") || kunciArr[i].equals("f")){
                kunciArrNumb[i]="5";
            }
            else if(kunciArr[i].equals("G") || kunciArr[i].equals("g")){
                kunciArrNumb[i]="6";
            }
            else if(kunciArr[i].equals("H") || kunciArr[i].equals("h")){
                kunciArrNumb[i]="7";
            }
            else if(kunciArr[i].equals("I") || kunciArr[i].equals("i")){
                kunciArrNumb[i]="8";
            }
            else if(kunciArr[i].equals("J") || kunciArr[i].equals("j")){
                kunciArrNumb[i]="9";
            }
            else if(kunciArr[i].equals("K") || kunciArr[i].equals("k")){
                kunciArrNumb[i]="10";
            }
            else if(kunciArr[i].equals("L") || kunciArr[i].equals("l")){
                kunciArrNumb[i]="11";
            }
            else if(kunciArr[i].equals("M") || kunciArr[i].equals("m")){
                kunciArrNumb[i]="12";
            }
            else if(kunciArr[i].equals("N") || kunciArr[i].equals("n")){
                kunciArrNumb[i]="13";
            }
            else if(kunciArr[i].equals("O") || kunciArr[i].equals("o")){
                kunciArrNumb[i]="14";
            }
            else if(kunciArr[i].equals("P") || kunciArr[i].equals("p")){
                kunciArrNumb[i]="15";
            }
            else if(kunciArr[i].equals("Q") || kunciArr[i].equals("q")){
                kunciArrNumb[i]="16";
            }
            else if(kunciArr[i].equals("R") || kunciArr[i].equals("r")){
                kunciArrNumb[i]="17";
            }
            else if(kunciArr[i].equals("S") || kunciArr[i].equals("s")){
                kunciArrNumb[i]="18";
            }
            else if(kunciArr[i].equals("T") || kunciArr[i].equals("t")){
                kunciArrNumb[i]="19";
            }
            else if(kunciArr[i].equals("U") || kunciArr[i].equals("u")){
                kunciArrNumb[i]="20";
            }
            else if(kunciArr[i].equals("V") || kunciArr[i].equals("v")){
                kunciArrNumb[i]="21";
            }
            else if(kunciArr[i].equals("W") || kunciArr[i].equals("w")){
                kunciArrNumb[i]="22";
            }
            else if(kunciArr[i].equals("X") || kunciArr[i].equals("x")){
                kunciArrNumb[i]="23";
            }
            else if(kunciArr[i].equals("Y") || kunciArr[i].equals("y")){
                kunciArrNumb[i]="24";
            }
            else if(kunciArr[i].equals("Z") || kunciArr[i].equals("z")){
                kunciArrNumb[i]="25";
            }
            else{
                kunciArrNumb[i]=Integer.toString(26 + Integer.parseInt(kunciArr[i]));
            }
        }
        return kunciArrNumb;
    }

public void toASCII(String leno, int jumKat, String ambilKunci){
    final EditText teksEnkrip = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.teks_enkrip);
    final TextView txtResultXOR = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtResultXOR);

    byte[] b = leno.getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);
    int ascii [] = new int[jumKat];
    for(int i = 0;i<jumKat;i++) {
        ascii[i]=b[i];
    }

    String ascii2 [] = new String[jumKat];
    for(int i = 0;i<jumKat;i++) {
        ascii2[i]=String.valueOf(b[i]);
        Log.d("ascii2",ascii2[i]);
    }


    String binKunci[] = toASCIIkunci(ambilKunci, jumKat);

    int resultXOR[] = new int[jumKat];

    for (int i=0;i<jumKat;i++){
        resultXOR[i]=Integer.parseInt(ascii2[i])^Integer.parseInt(binKunci[i]);
        Log.d("XOR",String.valueOf(resultXOR[i])); //this value that i need the resultXOR
    }

    String finalText = new String();
    finalText=finalen(resultXOR, jumKat);
    teksEnkrip.setText(finalText);

}


public String[] toASCIIkunci(String ambilKunci, int jumKat){
    byte[] bKunci = ambilKunci.getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);
    String desKunci[] = new String[jumKat];
    for(int i=0;i<jumKat;i++){
        desKunci[i]=String.valueOf(bKunci[i]);
        Log.d("desKun",desKunci[i]);
    }
    return desKunci;
    /*String binKunci[]=new String[jumKat];
    for(int i=0;i<jumKat;i++){
        binKunci[i]= Integer.toBinaryString(bKunci[i]);
        Log.d("kunciBin", String.valueOf(binKunci[i]));
    }
    return binKunci;*/
}


public String finalen(int[] resultXOR, int jumKat){
    String[] finalText= new String[jumKat];
    for (int i=0;i<jumKat;i++){
        if(resultXOR[i] == 0){
            finalText[i]="a";
        }
        else if(resultXOR[i] == 1){
            finalText[i]="b";
        }
        else if(resultXOR[i] == 2 ){
            finalText[i]="c";
        }
        else if(resultXOR[i] == 3){
            finalText[i]="d";
        }
        else if(resultXOR[i] == 4){
            finalText[i]="e";
        }
        else if(resultXOR[i] == 5 ){
            finalText[i]="f";
        }
        else if(resultXOR[i] == 6){
            finalText[i]="g";
        }
        else if(resultXOR[i] == 7 ){
            finalText[i]="h";
        }
        else if(resultXOR[i] == 8){
            finalText[i]="i";
        }
        else if(resultXOR[i] == 9 ){
            finalText[i]="j";
        }
        else if(resultXOR[i] ==10 ){
            finalText[i]="k";
        }
        else if(resultXOR[i] == 11){
            finalText[i]="l";
        }
        else if(resultXOR[i] ==12 ){
            finalText[i]="m";
        }
        else if(resultXOR[i] == 13){
            finalText[i]="n";
        }
        else if(resultXOR[i] ==14 ){
            finalText[i]="o";
        }
        else if(resultXOR[i] ==15 ){
            finalText[i]="p";
        }
        else if(resultXOR[i] ==16 ){
            finalText[i]="q";
        }
        else if(resultXOR[i] == 17){
            finalText[i]="r";
        }
        else if(resultXOR[i] ==18 ){
            finalText[i]="s";
        }
        else if(resultXOR[i] == 19 ){
            finalText[i]="t";
        }
        else if(resultXOR[i] == 20 ){
            finalText[i]="u";
        }
        else if(resultXOR[i] == 21){
            finalText[i]="v";
        }
        else if(resultXOR[i] == 22){
            finalText[i]="w";
        }
        else if(resultXOR[i] == 23){
            finalText[i]="x";
        }
        else if(resultXOR[i] == 24){
            finalText[i]="y";
        }
        else if(resultXOR[i] == 25){
            finalText[i]="z";
        }else if(resultXOR[i] == 26){
            finalText[i]="1";
        }else if(resultXOR[i] == 27){
            finalText[i]="2";
        }else if(resultXOR[i] == 28){
            finalText[i]="3";
        }else if(resultXOR[i] == 29){
            finalText[i]="4";
        }else if(resultXOR[i] == 30){
            finalText[i]="5";
        }else if(resultXOR[i] == 31){
            finalText[i]="6";
        }else if(resultXOR[i] == 32){
            finalText[i]="7";
        }else if(resultXOR[i] == 33){
            finalText[i]="8";
        }else if(resultXOR[i] == 34){
            finalText[i]="9";
        }
    }
    String finalString = new String();
    for (int i=0;i<jumKat;i++){
         finalString = finalString +finalText[i];
    }
    return finalString;
}

public String ASCIIXOR (String ambilKunci, String ambilKataHasil, int jumKat){
    byte[] bKunci = ambilKunci.getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);
    String desKunci[] = new String[jumKat];
    for(int i=0;i<jumKat;i++){
        desKunci[i]=String.valueOf(bKunci[i]);
    }

    byte[] bHasil = ambilKataHasil.getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);
    String desHasil [] = new String[jumKat];
    for(int i=0;i<jumKat;i++){
        desHasil[i]=String.valueOf(bHasil[i]);
    }

    int resultXORDec[] = new int[jumKat];

    for (int i=0;i<jumKat;i++){
        resultXORDec[i]=Integer.parseInt(desHasil[i])^Integer.parseInt(desKunci[i]);
        Log.d("XORDEC",String.valueOf(resultXORDec[i]));
    }

    String resultXORDecStr = new String();
    resultXORDecStr = finalen(resultXORDec, jumKat);

    //ambilKunci OK diambiil dari atas


} // handling for dekripButton
```

Comment: If you want in same page and same class, use the global array. if you want the encrypted value even after closing the app then use the SQLite data base. store the encrypted value to table and use whenever you want. If you do not want to store the encrypted value to the mobile then use rest call to store the data in server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to get data out of a function. You can create another function in your activity that takes an array and call that from the end of your button press. Such as call

```
public void encrytpedData(String[] encryption){
    //You can now use your array here
}
```

You can also declare an Array outside of the onClick fucntion and then set that equal to the encrypted Array inside of the button onClick function. If you do this make sure you initialize it first or you could get a null pointer exception.